# How to get the parent of a menu?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I'm trying to get the component in which a menu is linked.
Take a look:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    id: 'MyButton',
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    menuAlign: 'tl-bl',
    menu: {
        itemId: 'MyMenu',        
        forceLayout: true,
        items:
        [
            {
                text  : 'Option 1',
                itemId: 'MyItemMenu1'
            }, {
                text  : 'Option 2',
                itemId: 'MyItemMenu2'
            }, {
                text   : 'Get the parent!',
                itemId : 'MyItemMenu3',
                handler: function(){
                    
                    // Get the item menu.
                    var MyItemMenu3 = this; 
                    alert(MyItemMenu3.getItemId()); 
                    
                    // Get the menu.
                    var MyMenu = MyItemMenu3.ownerCt; 
                    alert(MyMenu.getItemId());
                    
                    // Try to get the button.
                    var MyButton = MyMenu.ownerCt; 
                    alert(MyButton);                    
                    
                    // Returns:                    
                    // 'MyItemMenu3'
                    // 'MyMenu'
                    // undefined                 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Online example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RobertoSchuster/mGLVF/

Any idea?

Comment: I'm learning EXT myself so I'm not too sure what's going on but I think I was able to get it this way: console.log(MyMenu.floatParent.id);

Comment: Ok I'll submit it as an answer :) Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm learning EXT myself so I'm not too sure what's going on but I think I was able to get it this way: `console.log(MyMenu.floatParent.id)`;

Comment: yea would think i simple up() call would do the trick. but no :) thanks for your answer... worked a charm

Answer (score 3):

In our ExtJS 4 project, we eventually just patched the `up()` function on `AbstractComponent`

```
Ext.AbstractComponent.override({
    up: function(selector) {
        var result = this.ownerCt||this.floatParent;
        if (selector) {
            for (; result; result = result.ownerCt||result.floatParent) {
                if (Ext.ComponentQuery.is(result, selector)) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

This makes `up()` walk up the `ownerCt` chain, but if `ownerCt` isn't defined, it looks to `floatParent`.

Now you can call `cmp.up('some-selector');` even if its a menu or menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('My-Button').menu.refOwner
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var MyButton = MyItemMenu3.up('button');
```

or for ExtJS3:

```
var MyButton = MyItemMenu3.findParentByType('button');
```

Comment: I tried both,but always return undefined. It works with MyMenu.floatParent. (:
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of ExtJS at least (4.2), every Ext.menu.Item has a `parentMenu` property that can access the parent menu. You might subclass this for custom menu items.